# Firemonkey style.png structure

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey

I am experimenting with custom styles design for Delphi XE3 Firemonkey, and can easily generate my styles.png and load it back.  The problem is mapping which element appears where on the map.

Other than manually going over the 100s of styles to find a location, is there an index for which color strip in styles.png designates which style?  Would save long hours of work if there is one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The position in the image depends on the style, there is no 'standard' position.

If you want to simply 'repaint' an existing style image, try comparing the appearance of components at various states with the original image, or look at the various TRectAnimations attached to the TSubImages in the component's style.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was hoping to avoid, see my question above :)